# spring mvc annotation many servlet dispatcher

Tags: spring, annotations, servlet-dispatching

Hi I am just starting to learn Spring mvc, I use spring mvc @annotation  and I have 3 servlets dispatchers (appservlet, admin, student):

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>   
    <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/admin-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>student</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.admin</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>student</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.student</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

After a test in a method I want a redirect to another servlet dispatcher, either the .admin or a .student. How can I do that please?

**@controller**

```
@Controller
public class AuthentificationController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "verifier", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView redir(@ModelAttribute("per") Personne per,
            HttpSession session) {

        if (p1.equals(per)) {
            session.setAttribute("login", per);
            ModelAndView M = new ModelAndView(".admin");
            return M;
        }

        if (p2.equals(per)) {
            ModelAndView M = new ModelAndView(".student");
            return M;
        } else {
            ModelAndView M = new ModelAndView("home");
            return M;
        }

    }
}
```

**The problem** is that `ModelAndView` returns (.jsp) but I want a redirection for another servlet-dispatcher !!

Comment: Do more studying... Read [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting-redirect-view).

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "verifier", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String redir(@ModelAttribute("per") Personne per, HttpSession session) {
    if (p1.equals(per)) {
        session.setAttribute("login", per);
        return "redirect:.admin";
    } else if (p2.equals(per)) {
        return "redirect:.student"
    } else {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how you would create a method that returns either a `String` or `ModelAndView` :). (Well you could return `Object` but still). Why not simply 'return "home";` in the other case.